# Build all solutions within a tree using Cake (C# make)?

Tags: c#, msbuild, cakebuild

I have multiple VS solutions within the same directory tree and would like to build all of them using Cake. Is there a way to build all of them without putting them one by one into the build script?

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes that's certainly possible using the built-in globber features, example:

```
var solutions           = GetFiles("./**/*.sln");

Task("Build")
    .IsDependentOn("Clean")
    .IsDependentOn("Restore")
    .Does(() =>
{
    // Build all solutions.
    foreach(var solution in solutions)
    {
        Information("Building {0}", solution);
        MSBuild(solution, settings =>
            settings.SetPlatformTarget(PlatformTarget.MSIL)
                .WithProperty("TreatWarningsAsErrors","true")
                .WithTarget("Build")
                .SetConfiguration(configuration));
    }
});
```

Similarly you can do the same before build with nuget restore, example

```
Task("Restore")
    .Does(() =>
{
    // Restore all NuGet packages.
    foreach(var solution in solutions)
    {
        Information("Restoring {0}...", solution);
        NuGetRestore(solution);
    }
});
```

And a clean task could be adapted like this

```
var solutionPaths       = solutions.Select(solution => solution.GetDirectory());

Task("Clean")
    .Does(() =>
{
    // Clean solution directories.
    foreach(var path in solutionPaths)
    {
        Information("Cleaning {0}", path);
        CleanDirectories(path + "/**/bin/" + configuration);
        CleanDirectories(path + "/**/obj/" + configuration);
    }
});
```